# Building a link based on current Controller name and Current Action name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following which show the navigation path of the user inside my _layout share view:-

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li>
<a href="#">@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue
    </a> <span class="divider">/</span>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

but i have the following two questions:-

1. Is using `ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue` the right way to get the controller name
2. how i can build the href of the a links to point to the required path ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the controller name using the `RouteData`:

```
var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
```

You can then build an [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click me", "View", controller)
```